# Update button array and export

Tags: c#, winforms, export-to-excel

I am creating a small program that generates a button grid. I then export this grid to MS Excel using a separate export class that I have created. The grid is generated when the form is loaded, a `numericUpDown` allows me to decide on the number of rows that I want the grid to have, when I press the Gen button the grid is successfully exported to Excel. However when I modify the size of the grid and give it less rows and click the Gen button again the exported data is not updated correctly the image below explains what I mean:

[image]

This is the code i have behind the form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttons = new Button[col][];
        states = new FormState[col][];
        for (Int32 c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            buttons[c] = new Button[col];
            states[c] = new FormState[col];
        }

    }

    private void loadMe()
    {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
        placeRows();

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadMe();

    }

     private void btnGen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         loadMe();

     }
}
```

I know that I might have to reset the button array but not quite sure how to make it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buttons` array is created just once during app startup, and each Generate just overrides Buttons in cells, leaving old buttons untouched; so Export class still use everything you've added to `buttons` array so far.

The easiest way to fix it without rewriting your code is to move `buttons = new Button[col][];` part from `Form1` ctor to `loadMe` method.